# Unable to login to WSJ using HtmlUnit/HttpClient

Tags: java, htmlunit, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am a paid member of WSJ. I want to login to WSJ using HtmlUnit, but am unable to do so. Following is my code :

```
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_24);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false); 
    webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
    webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);


    final HtmlPage page1 =  WebClient.getPage("https://id.wsj.com/access/50f57264bd7fb2d2f6629af6/latest/login_standalone.html");
    final HtmlForm form = page1.getForms().get(0);  

    final HtmlTextInput textField =  form.getInputByName("username");
    final HtmlPasswordInput pwd =  form.getInputByName("password");        
    textField.setValueAttribute("xxxxx");
    pwd.setValueAttribute("xxxx");   

    final HtmlSubmitInput button = (HtmlSubmitInput) form.getInputsByValue("Log In").get(0);
    final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
```

I don't know where am missing.. 
Earlier i used Apache HttpClient but still no sucess.

httpClient Code :

```
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
    HttpPost httpGet = new HttpPost("https://id.wsj.com/access/50f57264bd7fb2d2f6629af6/latest/login_standalone.html");
    httpGet.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    httpGet.setHeader("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate");
    httpGet.setHeader("Host","id.wsj.com");
    httpGet.setHeader("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0");
    httpGet.setHeader("X-HTTP-Method-Override","POST");
    httpGet.setHeader("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest");

    List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("landing_page", "http%3A%2F%2Findia.wsj.com%2F"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("realm", "default"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("template", "default"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "xxxx"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "xxxx"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("savelogin", "true"));

    httpGet.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

    HttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httpGet, httpContext);

    System.out.println(response1.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet("http://online.wsj.com/news/articles/SB10001424052702304834704579404391984581058?mod=WSJ_LatestHeadlines&mg=reno64-wsj");

    response1 = httpclient.execute(getRequest, httpContext);
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    IOUtils.copy(response1.getEntity().getContent(), writer, "UTF-8");
    String theString = writer.toString();
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("C:/Users/xxxsx/Desktop/xx.html");
    fileWriter.write(theString);
    fileWriter.close();
```

Please help guys?

**Guys finally using Selenium to login!**

Comment: Have u receive any exception while using HTMLUNIT ? or can u paste username,password and click button html code

Comment: no sir, no exception generated. No i can't make user/pass public

Comment: I dnt ask credential,just read again i ask html code.I have one question when i enter dummy username\password and click on button no action happen ? How this page work, in this case wrong username/password message must come..

Comment: sir which html code ?
http://s9.postimg.org/k6pads3r3/stackoverflow.png

Comment: yes i found the code.My answer works ??

Answer (score 0):

happily using `Selenium` to login successfully !